# Postman mock example response json data to include pathParms or queryParms or put body json object

Tags: postman, postman-mocks

I am using Postman 7.34.0

Now i am testing to use Postman to create mock server and mock data for the request.

After some study, i still did not get to make a flexible response in the mock data.

I have the update api and i will set pathParams, queryParams and also body to update the data.

So i want my mock data response to include some of the data from the update request.

I also check this [Postman Mock Data](https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/matching-algorithm/), it has the below description to use {{userId}} in the response.

[image]

For example
PUT {baseUrl}/:ouId/:customerServiceId
[image]

So I added the mock example to response like below:
[image]

But when i sent the update request, i got as below:
[image]

I am wondering if i am doing wrong or postman not support the features?

And also would like to know does postman support mock response to have scripting. I just saw the 'Pre request script' and 'Test' can write script. For the mock example, it seems can only add the static data and not able to write script to build up the fake response data structure.

Comment: Hi You can do this my answer was incorrect

Comment: I have updated the answer with the correct steps

Answer (score 5):

**Update:**

You can use dynamic varaible for mock servers please ignore previous answer

**What you have to do is :**

**1) in your example set header as:**

```
Content-Type : application/json
```

[image]

**2) Now in example body give the response you want as json:**

[image]

**3) Now create variable and values for this in the environment variable:**

[image]

**4) Now edit the mock server and make sure this environment is selected as the environment for the mock server:**

**Edit:**
[image]

**Add:**

[image]

and save it .

**Output from mock server :**

[image]

**IGNORE BELOW ANSWER:**

If you read the documentation:

https://learning.postman.com/docs/designing-and-developing-your-api/mocking-data/matching-algorithm/

> You can use the same variables in the example’s response to use their
> captured values. Taking the same example, you can add a request body
> for the same example like this:
>
> This will pass the value captured from the wildcard segment with the
> same variable name into the response.

So only variable captured in url wildcard will be passed to the response . Path variable are not normal varaibles so it cannot be set in mock response instead you can

**url as :** {{url}}/test/{{myuuid}}

and in body you can call this as {{myuuid}}

where myuuid is a variable defined in global, collection ,environment,data, or local scope

you can see my mock server response body has the value of myuuid variable defiend in environment variables:

[image]

Comment: The reason I am adding mock response data is that the server side implementation is not ready and I want to add mock data for the request in the web app. 

According to the above replied, i need to manually modify variables or response to get what i want in the response when i send a request from my web app. It seems quite inconvenient to use.

Comment: what is your api endpint

Comment: Mock server indeed requires you to hard code expectations as example , thats how every mock server works